# how can I access the electrical panel box

Tags: wiring

Can you access the electrical panel box via the sides and/or bottom of the box rather than enter via the top where it appears congested and close to the main terminals.

Comment: Pictures would help. Normally, yes, but it depends on any other constraints you may have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use sides, bottom, back, or even make your own hole (within reason).

All of them have knockouts (though the back tends to be fairly sparse).

If you come *through* a joist, you may have trouble attaching a cable clamp.  I would install a metal box (say: 6x6) on the other side of the joist, use a Rigid short pipe (conduit nipple) through the joist with about 1/2" of thread exposed on both sides, and clamp it down hard with conduit nuts. Then I'd bring a ground wire through to ground the metal box, and bring my cables into that box. Tie the grounds to the box, and tie the hot-neutral to THHN wires to extend into the panel.